# GWT CELLTABLE : Is it possible that all column values from particular row restore to old value?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

Is it possible that all column values from particular row restore to
old value ?

```
|| ID || Dept || Code || RNO || RCode|| .....................................................||ZCode ||
|| 1  ||  CS   || 001  ||  3      ||  030||...................................................||Q1||
|| 2  ||  DS   || 001  ||  5      ||  040||.....................................................||S1 ||
```

Suppose In above editable grid I changed 1st record i.e

```
|| 1  ||  CS   || 001  ||  3      ||  030||.....................................................||Q1||
```

changed to

```
|| 1  ||  BP   || 010  ||  3      ||  003||.....................................................||Q1||
```

Is there any way to restore old object(row) values instead to clearing
cell view data for each column and redraw editable grid.

In Short revert record to old value which is selected by our checkbox
(All or selected chkbox only i.e `selectionModel.isSelected(object)` )

My Grid contain (2-N) column so I am asking this question ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a data provider to provide data to the CellTable? You could clone the row data before rendering the table (or on edit) and when you needed to revert you could copy items back in to the data provider and call `table.redraw();`